# Изменить значение пути для "/" php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, config, path

Помогите решить такую проблему:
разрабатывая программу на локальном сервере (WAMP 3) у меня работали нормально пути в функциях типа

```
require_once "/db_conn.php";
```

файл db_conn.php лежит внутри D:\web-server\www\my_app\

скинув приложение на веб-сервер, мои пути перестали работать - пишет

```
Warning: require_once(/db_conn.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\web-server\www\my_app\index.html on line 2
```

вызвав функцию на локальной машине realpath("/") мне выдало D:\
на сервере получил аналогичный результат

на локальной машине результат функции get_include_path(); был .;C:\php\pear 
такой же результат никуда не ведущий в моей файловой системе был и на сервере. тоесть от настройки в php.ini для переменной include_path ничего не зависит.

подскажите как сделать так, чтобы заработали пути относительно / как относительно D:\web-server\www\my_app а не относительно D:\ при учёте что на веб-сервере стоит несколько приложений и глобально менять конфиг php для того чтобы он работал только с my_app нельзя

как это может реально сделать через .htaccess?

Comment: используйте волшебную константу `__DIR__` http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: не вариант, эта константа получает путь по сути тот же самый что делает "./", и это получается всеравно путь от папки в которой лежит файл, а мне нужно именно чтобы все пути указанные в скриптах через "/" расчитываелись именно от D:\web-server\www\my_app

Comment: Ну так `./` и `/` - это две очень большие разницы какбы

Comment: ./ как я понимаю нас возвращает к каталогу в котором находится файл из которого был вызван ./ . В то время как / должен предоставлять путь относительно корня сайта. Но он получает у меня уж слишком корень сайта

Comment: Ну, скажем так, если приложение построено архитектурно грамотно, то для любой задачи должно хватать `__DIR__` . Если не хватает - имеет смысл пересмотреть архитектуру - такой косвенный индикатор. :)